# When trying to load test ads on physical device, no ads are being displayed

Tags: android

I'm testing this on Android Studio on a Samsung S8. I'm using the following dependency for ads:

`implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.0'`

So the first code I added was to initialize mobile ads:

In `MainActivity.onCreate()`

```
        MobileAds.initialize(this,"ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713");
```

Then I create a simple banner ad, load it, and display it (in `MainActivity.onStart()`)

```
        banner_ad = new AdView(this);
        banner_ad.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);

            banner_ad.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111");




        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        banner_ad.loadAd(adRequest);
```

In both cases, `testing_ads` is true. It just makes the `AdUnitId` set to the test unit id.

I dont know if this is necessary at all, but I added it anyway in `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

I get this message:

`I/Ads: Ad is not visible. Not refreshing ad.
       Scheduling ad refresh 60000 milliseconds from now.`

No ads of any kind are displaying though, and for some reason my app is slowing down drastically. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Please note that you haven't added your AdView to the view hierarchy. Here is how to do it,

```
banner_ad = new AdView(this);
banner_ad.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
banner_ad.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111");
// Get the Layout of Main activity
// Add the banner_ad view to the layout
// Now your ad will be visible 

// Following is just an example. Replace with your actual main layout!
// LinearLayout mainView = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.main_view);
// mainView.addView(banner_ad);
```